# Adding search key value into a B+ tree

Tags: tree, b-plus-tree

I have this question on one of my practice paper and i was wondering how do i go about doing it. Any help is welcome.

Consider the following B+-tree, where a node can contain two 
search key values and three pointers.

[image]

Redraw the B+-tree after inserting a new record with search key value 38. (For 
simplicity, your figure may include only the affected nodes)

**This is what i thought should be the answer**
[image]

Comment: Have you tried to do it? What is your question?

Comment: @Ilya yes i did. What i did was to add 38 next to 31 and restructure the tree all the way till the root. But it just seems weird

Comment: Ok, you know how to add new value in tree and how to restruct tree after extension. What exactly is weird from your point of view? Try to explain! We don't want to guess using only telepathy.

Comment: @Ilya i have attached my answer. Does it look correct ?

Comment: It looks like you have three instances of '38' after restruction. But I expect only two, since you added '38' when you had only one '38'. Is it misprint?

Comment: @Ilya nope its not a misprint. What would yours look like ?

Comment: Why do you have three instances of '38' after adding another one to only one? I don't understand, why do you think that it is correct.